# unable to resolve docker endpoint

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

Post my latest Docker Update installation i am getting below error

```
PS C:\Users\vpasumar> docker ps -a
unable to resolve docker endpoint: default orchestrator is kubernetes but unable to resolve kubernetes endpoint: Error loading config file "C:\Users\vpasumar\.kube\config": yaml: control characters are not allowed
```

I see docker as running and kubernetes as 'starting' only. I did not start after much of time also.

Any idea, how to access docker.

Comment: Please also provide docker version, kuebernetes version, also provide the contents for config

Comment: Try deleting "C:\Users\vpasumar.kube\config" file once and then run, it might help, if there is some issue with config file.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you have docker stack defaulted to be deployed to `Kubernetes` in other words Kubernetes is the default orchestrator in your machine.

You can disable this easily from `Docker Desktop` settings/preferences, uncheck `Deploy Docker Stacks to Kubernetes by default`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, problem disappears after unchecking the option.

Answer (score 2):

I am using docker desktop 3.6.0 and i don't have option to select or unselect Default Stack.

However, Removing following statement from C:\Users\your user\.docker\config.json

```
"stackOrchestrator": "kubernetes"
```

Run any docker command again, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `C:\Users\vpasumar\.kube\config` file; the issue is now solved. I'm able to use docker command correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using *Linux* and looking to **undo** and **reset the local environment**
Try :

```
eval $(docker-machine env --unset)
```

You can refere to this answer of Elton Stoneman [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038572/eval-docker-machine-env-default)

Hope this helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue:

`kubectl config set-context docker-desktop`
or
`kubectl config set-context minikube`

Docker needs a default kubernetes endpoint.