# Docker is unable to resolve docker and Kubernetes endpoing

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-daemon

When I am running the `docker info` command, I am getting the below error. The docker desktop showing the status as `running`.

`unable to resolve docker endpoint: default orchestrator is kubernetes but unable to resolve kubernetes endpoint: invalid configuration: [unable to read client-cert C:\Users\classpath\.minikube\client.crt for minikube due to open C:\Users\classpath\.minikube\client.crt: The system cannot find the file specified., unable to read client-key C:\Users\classpath\.minikube\client.key for minikube due to open C:\Users\classpath\.minikube\client.key: The system cannot find the file specified., unable to read certificate-authority C:\Users\classpath\.minikube\ca.crt for minikube due to open C:\Users\classpath\.minikube\ca.crt: The system cannot find the file specified.]`
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385542/unable-to-resolve-docker-endpoint ? may it help